# Evaluation of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\sum^{n}_{k=1}\left(k^{999}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)}$

Tags: limits

> Evaluation of $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\sum^{n}_{k=1}\left(k^{999}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)}$$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ First we will calculate $$\sum^{n}_{k=1}\left(k^{999}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)=n^{1000}\sum^{n}_{k=1}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{999}\cdot \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum^{n}_{k=1}\sqrt{\frac{n}{k}}$$

Now How can I solve afeter that, Help me

Thanks in Advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle a_n=\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\Big(k^{999}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\Big)}$. Notice that $$1 <a_n<\sqrt[n]{2\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{999}}=\sqrt[n]{2}~\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{999}}<\sqrt[n]{2}~\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=1}^{n}n^{999}}=\sqrt[n]{2}~\sqrt[n]{n^{1000}}=\sqrt[n]{2}~(\sqrt[n]{n})^{1000},$$ and both sequences $\sqrt[n]{2},~(\sqrt[n]{n})^{1000}$ converge to $1$. Therefore, by the sandwich theorem, your limit exists and is equal to $1.$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Note that for $k \ge 1$ we have
$$
k^{999} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} < 2k^{999}
$$
and so your limit becomes
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{2\sum_{k=1}^n k^{999}}
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{2\Theta\left(n^{1000}\right)}
= 1...
$$